# Toggle LED Python 3.x tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, raspberry-pi3, gpio, led

I'm trying to toggle an LED on and off using a GUI.

When I execute the code I get a blank box just saying "tk" for the title.

```
import tkinter as tk

class Application(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None): 
        super().__init__(master)
        self.pack()
        Label(frame, text='Turn LED ON').grid(row=0, column=0)
        Label(frame, text='Turn LED OFF').grid(row=1, column=0)

        self.button = Button(frame, text='LED 0 ON', command=self.convert0)
        self.button.grid(row=2, columnspan=2)

    def convert0(self, tog=[0]):
        tog[0] = not tog[0]
        if tog[0]:
            self.button.config(text='LED 0 OFF')
        else:
            self.button.config(text='LED 0 ON')

root = tk.Tk()
app = Application(master=root)
app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code needs several fixes.

First off, running it as is gave me the following error:

```
NameError: name 'Label' is not defined
```

And for sure, it is not.
What is defined is `tk.Label`, so let's change those two lines:

```
Label(frame, text='Turn LED ON').grid(row=0, column=0)
Label(frame, text='Turn LED OFF').grid(row=1, column=0)
```

into:

```
tk.Label(frame, text='Turn LED ON').grid(row=0, column=0)
tk.Label(frame, text='Turn LED OFF').grid(row=1, column=0)
```

Now, I'm raised the following error:

```
NameError: name 'frame' is not defined
```

And sure enough, it isn't either.
You're probably refering to the fact that the `Application` class extends the `tk.Frame` class.
Well, that's true, but that doesn't tell us what `frame` is.
I assume that `frame` means "the instance, but considered as a `Frame` instance".
In this case, `self` is enough (and it's actually what is needed).
So here we go, the following three lines:

```
tk.Label(frame, text='Turn LED ON').grid(row=0, column=0)
tk.Label(frame, text='Turn LED OFF').grid(row=1, column=0)

self.button = Button(frame, text='LED 0 ON', command=self.convert0)
```

become:

```
tk.Label(self, text='Turn LED ON').grid(row=0, column=0)
tk.Label(self, text='Turn LED OFF').grid(row=1, column=0)

self.button = Button(self, text='LED 0 ON', command=self.convert0)
```

Now, I'm told that

```
NameError: name 'Button' is not defined
```

I'm sure you're starting to understand the point.
So let's replace `Button` by `tk.Button`:

```
self.button = tk.Button(self, text='LED 0 ON', command=self.convert0)
```

And here you go, the window is displayed, with two labels and one nice button, whose text changes when clicked.

Comment: Thank you for the step by step fix!